# How to build pre-calculated histogram in Vega-Lite?

Tags: vega-lite

VegaLite can bin and aggregate himself. But I have complex calculation and build histogram separately.

The resulting data is following

```
bins = [1,  2,  3,  4] // 4 edges
//      |1-2|2-3|3-4|  // 3 bars

counts = [1,  2,  1]
```

The problem is - how to properly display bar edges - there are 3 bars, **but 4 edges**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify bin start and endpoints using the `x` and `x2` encodings. It's also helpful to specify `bin='binned'` which tells Vega-Lite that the data is pre-binned & triggers the same display defaults used when a bin operation appears in the specification. For example ([editor link](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4KABGBEAmCGAutIC4yghSA3WAbArgKYDOKYA2uBhMJAEYCWAdgIxksA0UjTATGby6QAxgHt8TeKVQsAvhyrVaPNqkHdm-VAGYhYiVIHzFGZc1VhdGvmQAse8ZOlg5JgLpVjmALawATgDWZPT+kAqYhExi0MwA5mToGJAAHgmQAGYMhLjQwSphUPAAngAOhMEAjviwkgyI8AxY5UI8ecxMhLleSclaaBlZOW023ZhFaZnZuagijoZCxWWV1bX1jeWyniCyQA)):

```
{
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"bin1": 1, "bin2": 2, "counts": 1},
      {"bin1": 2, "bin2": 3, "counts": 2},
      {"bin1": 3, "bin2": 4, "counts": 1}
    ]
  },
  "mark": "bar",
  "encoding": {
    "x": {"field": "bin1", "type": "quantitative", "bin": "binned"},
    "x2": {"field": "bin2"},
    "y": {"field": "counts", "type": "quantitative"}
  }
}
```

[image]

For more information, see [Using Vega-Lite with Binned data](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/bin.html#binned).